# Ler pares de valores inteiros usando tuplas em python

Tags: python

Sou nova por aqui, assim como na linguagem Python. Essa questão que lhes apresento, é referente a uma questão do trabalho da faculdade. Já tentei de todas as formas resolver e não consegui. Estou aqui por desespero mesmo. Aqui é minha última tentativa. Logo após a pergunta, está o que eu consegui fazer até agora - somente a letra A.

Faça um programa, contendo subprogramas, que leia pares de valores inteiros, x e y, até que o par de números zeros seja lido. Suponha que cada um destes pares representem um ponto no espaço bidimensional. Mantenha estes pontos como um vetor de tuplas (x,y). Após a entrada de todos pontos válidos, excetuando o par de zeros, escreva na saída padrão:

1. A quantidade de pontos válidos;
2. O vetor de pontos, escrevendo um ponto por linha;
3. Caso existam, quais os dois pontos mais próximos entre si. Caso haja empate, escreva um deles;
4. Caso existam, quais os dois pontos mais distantes entre si. Caso haja empate, escreva um deles;
5. Caso existam, quais são as médias das coordenadas x e y.

Definição

A distância entre dois pontos (xA,yA) e (xB,yB) é dada pela raiz quadrada da soma do quadrado das diferenças, (xA-xB) e (yA-yB).

O que eu fiz:

```
qtdParesLidos = 0
linhaLida = input()  # faz a leitura da primeira linha
x = float(linhaLida.split()[0])
y = float(linhaLida.split()[1])

while x != 0 or y != 0:  # repete até que o ponto 0 0 seja lido
    qtdParesLidos = qtdParesLidos + 1
    linhaLida = input()  # faz a leitura da próxima linha
    x = float(linhaLida.split()[0])
    y = float(linhaLida.split()[1])
```

Comment: Não consegui fazer sentido da sua dúvida. Você menciona em todos os lugares os números inteiros, mas no código você converteu para número de ponto flutuante/`float`? Seu problema é só essa questão, então todos os outros 4 pontos do trabalho são irrelevantes para a sua dúvida em específico?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código que você escreveu vai funcionar bem para ler os dados, e parar a entrada. A entrada deve ser de inteiros, mas as saídas de alguns dos itens pedidos é decimal, então não há problema em usar o `float` ao invés do `int`. Exceto que o item 2 pede a impressão das coordenadas entradas, então será melhor converte-los para inteiros no trabalho final.

Então, os pontos que me parece que você precisa entender para conseguir fazer o exercício todo:

1. Uma "tupla" em Python é uma sequência de valores - que em geral é declarada direto no código. É difernte das "listas" por que uma vez criadas não podem mais ser alteradas - tem o valor fixo. São criadas simplesmente colocando os valores desejados separados por vírgulas, e tudo isso dentro de parênteses (em alguns casos, os parenteses são até mesmo opcionais - basta separar valores por vírgula que o Python cria uma tupla). Exemplo: `ponto = (x, y)` ou `ponto = x, y`  são duas linhas que vão criar uma tupla em que o primeiro elemento terá o valor que está em x e o segundo o valor que está em y.  Para se recuperar o elemento é só usar `ponto[0]` (ou 1 entre colchetes, para o outro elemento). Listas e tuplas funcionam como "sequências" - e o número dentro do colchete é a posição do elemento desejado.
2. "Listas": são um outro tipo de sequência do Python. Ao contrário das "tuplas" podem ter seus elementos e seu comprimento alterado depois que são criadas. Um dos métodos mais usados é o `.append` - ele insere um novo elemento ao final da sequência. Ex:

--

```
coordenadas = []  # cria uma lista vazia
coordenadas.append(ponto)  # acrecenta o valor referenciado na variável "ponto" à lista.
```

O melhor jeito de entender listas é entrar no prompt interativo do Python e brincar um pouco - verifique o seu conteúdo, acrescente elementos com os métodos append(elemento) e  insert(posicao, elemento). Veja como pode recuperar elementos em posições específicas usando os colchetes. A documentação completa está aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html

Pergunta que se você souber responder vai ver que está no caminho certo: se cada elemento da lista for uma tupla com duas coordenadas, como eu faço para recuperar a "coordenada x" do elemento na posição 0 da lista? 
Parece difícil?- mas vamos por partes  - vamos supor que eu tenha o seguinte trecho de código:

```
x = 3
y = 4
ponto = (x, y)
coords = []
coords.append(ponto)
```

O que vai aparecer na tela se eu digirar `coords[0]`? E se eu digitar `ponto[0]` ?  (na dúvida, digite o trecho acima no prompt interativo do Python até não ter dúvidas).
E o que acontece se eu continuar essa sequência de comandos e digitar:

```
consulta = coords[0]
x1 = consulta[0]
```

Qual será o valor em `x1`? Será que eu preciso da variável intermediária "consulta"? Ou dá pra escrever direto `coords[0][0]` (experimente no prompt interativo)

3. você também precisa saber que existe a função embutida `len` que sempre retorna o comprimento de uma sequência . Ex: `len(coords)`.
4. Lembre-se que o comando `for` em Python, ao contrário do `for` em outras linguagens sempre percorre uma sequência - o corpo do `for` é executado uma vez para cada elementode uma sequência. 
   Ex.:

--

```
for elemento in coords:
       print("A coordenada x nesse elemento é", elemento[0])
```

Os itens 3 e 4 do exercício são os mais complicados mesmo, e os que exigem alguma lógica de programação. Espero que os conceitos que eu descrevi acima te ajudem a entender bem o que precisa até essa parte.
Para fazer o 3 você vai precisar:

1. de uma variável para guardar os items mais próximos já encontrados - lembre-se que a variável pode ser uma tupla ou uma lista, portanto, os dois pontos que você vai precisar "lembrar" na resposta podem ficar na mesma variável
2. uma variável para guardar qual foi a menor distância já encontrada entre dois pontos. Inicialize-a com um valor grande;
3. um "for" para percorrer todos os pontos - dentro dele outro "for" para percorrer todos os pontos de novo. No corpo desse segundo "for" interno você: verifica se os pontos do primeiro for e do segundo são os mesmos. Se forem, continuar (veja o comando `continue`: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops ). Calcular a distância entre o ponto selecionado no primeiro for e no segundo - se for menor do que o menor valor que você já viu, guarde esses dois pontos, e o valor da distância encontrados.  Ao final dos dois "for",  a variável com os pontos vai ter o resultado que voce precisa imprimir.

Calcular a maior distância entre dois pontos deve ser tranquilo -  é quase a mesma coisa, é só usar a lógica de forma apropriada.

A média: basta ter variáveis para somar todos os valores de x, todos os valores de y, e dividir isso pelo total de pontos (que você já sabe calcular). 
Bom - espero que com isso você já tenha como caminhar bastante dentro do exercício

Comment: Poxa, muitíssimo obrigada. Me ajudou bastante. Já estava desistindo de fazer a questão. Tenha um bom dia.